# Any disadvantage to calling _documentSession.Store when updating existing documents in RavenDB?

Tags: ravendb

When creating new or updating existing documents in RavenDB, the documentation says to do it along these lines:

```
public string Save(Blogpost post)
{
    Blogpost model;

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(post.Id))
    {
        model = new Blogpost();
        _documentSession.Store(model);
    }
    else
    {
        model = _documentSession.Load<Blogpost>(post.SimpleId);
    }

    model.Text = template.Text;
    model.Name = template.Name;
    _documentSession.SaveChanges();

    return model.Id;
}
```

Someone on my team is doing saves another way for both creating new documents or updating existing ones:

```
public string Save(Blogpost post)
{
    _documentSession.Store(post);
    _documentSession.SaveChanges();
    return post.Id;
}
```

Is there any disadvantage to always calling `.Store()` even if the document already exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store will store this object in a new document. Use the change tracking feature built-in in the session object aka the Unit of Work pattern, like the docs suggest.

Comment: Which I agree with. Someone else came up with this idea, and I'd rather not arbitrarily shoot it down without understanding why. The advantage is it does make the code significantly cleaner in some areas.

Comment: synhershko is there some sort of reason to do this that I'm missing? In my over the wire tests it didn't seem to do anything to the raw traffic...

Comment: @JohnCulviner see my comments to your post. This turns to be a discussion which should really be made on the mailing list and not on SO.

Answer (score 5):

Jason,
Your code will always *overwrite* the document. Is that something that you want to do?

Comment: In about 1/2 of the use cases, completely overriding is fine. I questioned this approach he came up with, since I'm used to Entity Framework and typical the Unit of Work. I just wanted to make sure there were no underlying issues this approach will cause in our application.

Comment: A not so obvious side effect of the overwrite is that custom metadata values will be lost.

Comment: Yes, if you want to preserve metadata, load the document, update it, then call SaveChanges()

Answer (score 5):

If you are doing a rich client app and serializing the full **BlogPost** to the client like so:

```
//GET BlogPost/1
public BlogPost Get(int id)
{
    return _documentSession.Load<BlogPost>(id)
}
```

Then rehyrdating a full **BlogPost** on the server after a user has made changes. The below code appears to be more efficient than doing a Load and then a Store:

```
//POST BlogPost/
public void Post(BlogPost post)
{
    //blog post already has an Id in this example
    _documentSession.Store(post)
    _documentSession.SaveChanges(); 
}
```

When you do a

```
documentSession.Load<Blogpost>(id)
```

RavenDB returns the full JSON for the blog post that you *already have* just for you to overwrite it, turn around and re-save sending the full JSON for the blog post back again over the wire to Raven.

This means that doing a Load and Store when you already have all the data results in twice the network traffic to Raven for no added benefit that I can see using Fiddler.

Even if you were only changing a part of the object (say the Name of the BlogPost) the RavenDB .NET API still sends the full object over the wire when doing a:

- Load()
- make *some* changes (but not changes to everything)
- Store()
- SaveChanges()

Perhaps Ayende Rahien can enlighten us on anything I missed here?

Comment: You are missing 3 things: 1) The RavenDB client API uses caching, so if you already loaded it in Get loading it again in Post will generate minimum traffic, not the full JSON doc. If you get the full JSON doc, then its good that you loaded it again, since there were other changes while you worked on it. 2) In continuation to #1, it enables you to take advantage of Optimistic Concurrency, and 3) UoW is the proper way of doing those kind of things, mostly for the reasons I just mentioned.

Comment: Awesome, this was the answer we were looking for. I dont' know if I saw #1 occur in over the wire traffic but it could have been due to doing debugging. I think the Optimistic Concurrency is a good point. I suppose one could use Automapper to push the BlogPost from the client into the Load'ed<BlogPost> or does it matter? Good stuff! Perhaps  I/you could work on updating the documentation pages on this too.